# iOS UI query on background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I am doing some processing on a background thread.  That processing needs access to UI element information (like the position of a UIView).  From my research, it appears that the background thread should be allowed to "query" attributes of a UIView -- as long as it does NOT "change" any attributes.

I would feel better if anyone could substantiate my claim.  Small code snippet below.

```
// on background thread
UIView *view = [self.view viewWithTag:tag];
CGFloat xPosition = view.frame.origin.x;
```

Comment: Despite what Noah says, I sure as heck wouldn't do that. I wouldn't _touch_ the interface on anything but the main thread. However, GCD makes it trivial to pop out to main thread, get your info, and dive back into the background thread. Why take chances?

Comment: @matt: I agree with you 100%.  I originally wrote it exactly as you say.  The issue is I'm running ObjectiveC code called from JavaScriptCore -- which is running on a background thread.  Oddly, about 1-in-100 times the switch to mainThread will hang (dead lock).  So ... I reached out to the community for help.

Comment: Well, you might have mentioned that in your question, since JavaScriptCore is another can of worms. I know almost nothing about it but it seems incredibly cool. :) Nevertheless I _still_ advise against touching the interface on a background thread; what you need to do is solve the JavaScriptCore issue, not cheat on the interface touching. I suggest that you completely reask your question, being honest this time about what the problem is.

Comment: Found one BIG problem:  viewWithTag is NOT thread safe.  If you are creating views on the main UI thread, while a background thread asks "viewWithTag" -- boom.  Which means, my code above will NOT work on a background thread.  boo hoo.

Comment: Just obey the rules. UIKit is not thread safe. END OF STORY. Do Not Taunt Happy Fun Ball.